# FQL query: query with multiple stream_id gives too few records

Tags: facebook-fql

I would like to query public posts from multiple Pages.

My FQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT post_id, source_id FROM stream WHERE source_id in (157528807603192, 127531603328)
```

This query returns only about 6 records.

However, if I use the two source_id in two separate query I got more than 20 item for both of them:

```
SELECT post_id, source_id FROM stream WHERE source_id in = 157528807603192
```

I couldn't find anything in the documentation stating that if you query multiple source_id you need different permissions.

Can anyone explain me what is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer in the documentation. :(

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.get/

> "If you specify only one user ID in the source_ids array, you can
>   return, at minimum, the last 50 posts from that user's profile stream
>   (Wall) for the last 180 days (it likely can be more).
>
> If you specify more than one user ID in the source_ids array, you can
>   return posts in those streams only from the last few days (about one
>   week)."